# What type of a tool should I use to make a simple simulator in C or C++

Tags: c++, image, command, render

I'm a Rails/web developer with little experience with C++, so I'm not totally sure what direction to head in:  I'm looking to build a simple simulator that I can use to test an algorithm I'm building that converts standard images to radial coordinates, and all I really need to be able to do is to plot points (which will represent LEDs) on a blank window and continuously refresh them (the LEDs blink).  I don't want to build a gui; command line is fine, as I'll be the only person using the tool.

I'm not sure whether this is even possible or not... I did some Java programming years ago and I remember being able to pretty easily open a window and render images in it.  Is there a C++ equivalent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a perfect fit for a GUI application, rather than command line, as far as I understand.

But if you want something really simple, and not spend some time learning a GUI development framework (MFC, Qt, WxWidgets, etc), you should check the following resources:

- [character based basic console graphics](http://www.codecogs.com/pages/forums/pagegen.php?id=992)
- [some more advanced console graphics with blinking, box drawing, etc.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17482/Basic-Graphics-For-Your-Console-Applications)
- [using full GDI graphics on console](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216430/add-a-little-graphics-to-your-console)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy in C++, because there is no standard way in doing this. It's not part of the language. There are a lot of frameworks though, some lightweight and some bloating. It also depends your platform. Anyhow, I think I would use OpenGL and do that calculation thing in a shader. That way you don't have to recompile and rerun all the C++ code. You can even do it in way that updates the GPU shader whenever you save your shader file giving you immediate results.